# Drupal 7 - How to add custom translation text group for strings on a theme

Tags: drupal-7, translation

I have in my Drupal 7 some templates translated by `echo t("xyz")`. I can find all the strings in the translation administration interface, but the strings are mixed with all the default drupal strings.

I would like to search for just my own strings or strings that belong to a specific template (theme). Available filter options (not helping me):

- All text groups
- Build in intarface
- Node tyles
- Meta tag
- Menus
- Blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your own own **"Text Group"** using [hook_locale()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/function/hook_locale/7) function. Furthermore i18n module provides some more options.

- See more at the [i18n_string.api.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21i18n%21i18n_string%21i18n_string.api.php/7)
- See an example at https://groups.drupal.org/node/152929 (this is the "Contact Forms" text group)

An easy method would be to **create the custom "Text Group"** and then create a **.po** file with your **translation strings** and finally **import** it on the specific text group (admin/config/regional/translate/import).

Related question here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29125/use-a-custom-textgroup-from-t